# In Windows Event Logs, what is the difference between Windows EventId and EventRecordID

Tags: windows, events, event-log

I am not sure of the difference. They both seem like Primary Keys. Does one do something different than the other? The Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wes/eventschema-eventid-systempropertiestype-element) offers little explanation of the fields.

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">


<EventID>20</EventID> 

<Version>0</Version> 

<Level>4</Level> 

<Task>116</Task> 

<Opcode>0</Opcode> 

<Keywords>0x800000000000000</Keywords> 

<TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-27T04:56:25.280553800Z" /> 

<EventRecordID>7178</EventRecordID> 

<Correlation /> 

<Execution ProcessID="7992" ThreadID="1376" /> 

<Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Audio/PlaybackManager</Channel> 

<Computer>John-Desktop</Computer> 

<Security UserID="S-1-5-21-2026109775-3903604127-447048412-1001" /> 

</System>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **EventRecordID** is the index number of the event in that particular Event log.

For example, the first event written to your event-log will have 1 as EventRecordID, then the next will have 2 and so on

> **EventID** is used to identify different type of events.

Here are some examples of event ID and what they mean:

```
Event ID    Meaning

528         A user successfully logged on to a computer
529         The logon attempt was made with an unknown user name or bad password
530         The user account tried to log on outside of the allowed time
531         A logon attempt was made using a disabled account
532         A logon attempt was made using an expired account
```